# Outer apply in linq to sql

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, transactions

What's the linq to sql translation for this query

```
SELECT *    
FROM MasterTable AS [t0]
Outer APPLY UfnGetDetail([t0].x, [t0].y, z) AS [t2]
```

...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, it works with something like this

```
 var query = from mt in db.MasterTable
             let detailResult = db.UfnGetDetail(mt.x, mt.y, z).SingleOrDefault()...
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
from mt in dc.MasterTable
select dc.UfnGetDetail (mt.x, mt.y)
```